# adding elements in vectors (not matrices) in a list in R

Tags: r, list

Consider I have the following list in which each element of the list is a vector and not a matrix (with s number of cols and rows) -

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 

$b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to add across the elements (1,2 3..) of each vector (a, b, c) such that-

```
$Total
[1] 3 6 9 12 15
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: `Reduce(`+`, your_list)` or `colSums(do.call(rbind, your_list))`

Comment: or `do.call("+", list(1:10, 1:10))`.

Comment: Reduce is not working. I get the unexpected ',' error.

Comment: @tg110, put the "+" in quotes: `"+"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an R function for the element-wise summation of the matrices stored as elements in single list object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147655/is-there-an-r-function-for-the-element-wise-summation-of-the-matrices-stored-as)

Comment: since you have equal number of elements in each list element, you can also use `rowSums(as.data.frame(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
rowSums(simplify2array(lst))
```

where `lst` is your list.

Comment: It is simplify.

Comment: are you on phone?

Comment: Ohh, that is terrible.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi  Yes, I thought you got busy with some research work

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi  Good luck with the viva!