# How can I do list summation element-wise in R

Tags: r, list

this is very similar to

*[Is there an R function for the element-wise summation of the matrices stored as elements in single list object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147655/is-there-an-r-function-for-the-element-wise-summation-of-the-matrices-stored-as)*

How can I do list summation element-wise in R?

For example, I want

```
temp1<-list(c(rep(0,6)),c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
temp2<-list(c(2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

to yield

```
 3,5,7,9,11,13
```

Just simple `temp1[[2]] + temp2` doesn't work. Is there a special formula for it?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of what your lists look like. Also, does this have to generalize to situations where you have multiple lists or multiple items in each list? Or are you just adding two vectors from different lists?

Comment: I am trying to add different list : one is subset of list and the other is just list  itself. what lists look like is posted in here temp1 is composed of list 2, and I want only temp1[[[2]]] and the other list is composed of numeric

Comment: Do both vectors in the list have same length? You can simply try with mapply like:   `list(mapply(FUN = sum,temp2,temp1[[2]]))`.

Comment: this looks like the `+` operator would suffice. Have you tried something like `mapply("+",a,b)` where the lists are `a` and `b`?

Comment: `temp1[[2]] + temp2[[1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(`+`, temp1, temp2)[[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both the vectors in the list are of same length:

```
lst=list(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=c(2,3,4,5,6,7))   
list(mapply(FUN = sum,lst$a,lst$b))'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a list of more than 2 elements, where each element is a 2x2 matrix. I want to add up each of these 2x2 matrices, and I can do that by:

`my_list <- c(temp1, temp2) #make one list of the separate sublists`

`Reduce("+", my_list) #add the sublists together, element-wise`

If you do or don't want to include the first of your three sublists, you can use `Reduce("+", my_list)` or `Reduce("+", my_list[-1])`, respectively.